# How to register a com class created in c# at the time of running inno setup

Tags: c#, com, inno-setup, pascal

I have just found out that I can code in  c#  the functionality I require and then make it a com library to call it in inno setup. Below is the code I am playing with.

C# code:

```
namespace SetupUtility
{
[Guid("BC45B534-C9E7-4C43-B57C-56B77C1C6CEE")]
public interface IMyClass
{
    void WriteToFile(string filepath, string name, string orgName, string emailID);
}

 [Guid("9AB25B08-FF74-4ADA-9A16-62ADB4603A56"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyClass:IMyClass
{
    public void WriteToFile(string filepath,string name, string orgName, string emailID)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] strings = { name, orgName, emailID };
            File.WriteAllLines(filepath + "userDetails.txt", strings);
            MessageBox.Show("File Written Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

And below is an extract from the pascal script I have managed to write with much effort:

```
ExtractTemporaryFile('SetupUtility.dll');
Exec('{dotnet40}\regasm.exe','{tmp}\SetupUtility.dll', '', SW_SHOW,
 ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
obj := CreateOleObject('SetupUtility.MyClass');
obj.WriteToFile('{tmp}',ContactPerson, OrgName, Email);
```

The codes compile fine, but when I run the setup, I am getting the message "Class not registered." Where is the error coming from and what is the possible way out?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can create those classes via a COM client on the machine it was compiled on? You may also need the `/codebase` parameter.

Comment: Nothing jumps out, a bitness problem doesn't explain it.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to find out what registry key is missing.  And do make sure you have a minimum guarantee that regasm.exe actually executed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `ExpandConstant` when using constants like `{dotnet40}` and `{tmp}` from within code.

And you need `[assembly:ComVisible(true)]` in your AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Don't forget to unregister this component again when the installation completes (including when it completes unsuccessfully).

Personally, I wouldn't do it this way -- temporary COM registrations are very messy.  Ideally, write a native DLL for setup tasks (or do it directly in Inno script, if you're doing something simple like writing to a file).  If you definitely require .NET for some reason, then consider writing a console application and running that (with parameters if required) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should mark your types with `COMVisible` attributes first. It would also be useful to see the client side code (the one which creates the instance).

If you don't put your assembly into GAC (which requires that you sign it), you will need to run `regasm` with `/codebase` switch so that registry contains the location of your assembly. I usually add `/tlb` switch too, because I like to have type library available and you might need it for some marshaling scenarios.